# javascript default function value

Tags: javascript, function, default

Is there any reason why something like this would not work?

```
var classReplace = function(object, newClass, originalClass = "") {
    //do stuff
}
```

I keep getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = " error because I add in the

```
originalClass = ""
```

part

Comment: It won't work because JavaScript has no such language feature (at present anyway).

Comment: It'll be there in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: ES6 will have it: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:parameter_default_values. *"Is there any reason why something like this would not work?"* Because the language doesn't allow it.

Comment: so this is wrong?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters

Comment: *Warning: For Gecko 15 and upper versions.*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko

Comment: oh, so that's only for gecko with a version of 15 or more? not webkit or any other browser type?

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if originalClass was defined and if not then assign it "",

```
var classReplace = function(object, newClass, originalClass) {
 if( typeof(originalClass) === "undefined" ) originalClass = "";
 //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Pointy said, setting a default argument value in this way isn't possible in JavaScript,

You can, however, achieve similar results by checking if said argument is `undefined`, and if so, setting it equal to your desired default value:

```
var classReplace = function(object, newClass, originalClass) {
    if (originalClass === undefined) originalClass = "";
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't exist in JS out of the box, I can think of two options in addition to the other answers, that actually mimick the feature you are looking for.

a. **CoffeeScript**

Among other cool features, CS supports default function values:

```
var classReplace = (object, newClass, originalClass = "") ->
console.log(originalClass)
```

Of course this just gets interpreted as:

```
var classReplace = function(object, newClass, originalClass) {
  if (originalClass == null) {
    originalClass = "";
  }
  return console.log(originalClass);
};
```

But still nice to have for readability, and like I said, CS has a lot of other cool features, may be worth a look.

b. **Lo-Dash**'s `partialRight` method. ([link](http://lodash.com/docs#partialRight))

usage:

```
var originalFunction = function(a,b) { return a + b; },
    functionWithDefaultValues = _.partialRight(originalFunction, 1, 2);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/287ac/)

notes:

1. `_.partial`, for some reason, doesn't have the same behaviour.
2. `_.partialRight` appends the values from the right, so in the above, the default value for `b` is `1`.

Hope this helps.